# Value in sibling component is not same React

Tags: reactjs, components, state, siblings

I have 2 sibling Components - CardBoard and ModalWindow , I need to pass Id of CardBoard to ModalWindow when function handleModalOpen is called , i am using useState for changing state for changing  currentId ([currentId , setCurrentId]=useState(null)) and then passing it to ModalWindow component through contextApi , the problem is when i console.log value of currentId when Modal is firstly opened , the value is null even tho in useEffect that i do after the function in CardBoard the value is already changed , i tried to do the function async so it waits for setting the state and then opening the modal but it appears to not work.I would like to hear some ideas on how to fix this .

```
const handleModalOpen = () => {
    setCurrentCardBoardId(id);   //this changes the state
    setShowModal(true);          //this sets Modal open
  };

//useEffect ran in CardBoard component
useEffect(() => {
    console.log(currentCardBoardId);
  }, [handleModalOpen]); 

  const {currentCardBoardId,setCurrentCardBoardId } = useContext(settingsModalContext); //thats how i call it in ModalWindow component
```

Edit: this is my function that check if id hasnt updated while componend was rendered , doesnt work even tho console.log("The condition has been triggered") is logged in the console

```
const handleSubmit = async (e) => {
    
    setShowModal(false);
    setRefreshAlertOpen(true);

    try {
      checkForIdUpdate() //this checks whether the id was not updated
      const newTask = await axios.post("http://localhost:5000/taskData", task);
      console.log(newTask);
    } catch (error) {
      console.log(error);
    }
  };

const checkForIdUpdate = (e) => {
    if(currentCardBoardId!== null) {
      setTask((prevState) => ({ ...prevState, cardBoardId:`${currentCardBoardId}`}))
      console.log("The condition has been triggered")
    }
  }
```

Comment: Can you put both of your component codes to get a proper idea about the issue ?

Comment: Well the components have 300 lines of code together so i am not sure how to poste it here so it doesnt get too long